# How to enable line break at hyphens on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Chrome, IE, and Safari break lines at hyphens but Firefox doesn't.

Is there any way to make Firefox break lines at hyphens, like other browsers?

Comment: Which version of Firefox? Works fine for me without doing anything at all in FF9: http://jsfiddle.net/kVc6f/ Actually, I can't find a browser that this *doesn't* work in...

Comment: @WesleyMurch It doesn't break when the hyphen connects to a numeric character instead of an alphabet character, in Firefox, for whatever reason. http://jsfiddle.net/kVc6f/14/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Insert the `<wbr>` tag after the hyphen. [This tag](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html#wbr) is not present in any HTML specification (yet—it is in HTML5 drafts), but it has worked for a long time in browsers.

Firefox automatically treats a hyphen as allowing a line break after it when there are sufficiently many characters around the hyphen. But if you wish to allow line breaks more widely than that, use `<wbr>`, e.g. `pre-<wbr>war`.

Answer (score 14):

Not easily. Try inserting a zero-width space (`&#8203;`) after each hyphen. For example:

```
a-&#8203;really-&#8203;long-&#8203;hyphenated-&#8203;phrase
```

This will make Firefox wrap as if there's a space, but it won't visually display that space.

It's easier to implement this if you have something processing your output server-side. Just run hyphens through a quick string replace.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you seeing this issue in? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I know you're from ~2.5 years ago, but I'm still able to reproduce this in FF 33.  The other answer of using `<wbr>` worked for me.

Comment: Ugh, I can reproduce it in FF49 :/

Comment: Tried `<wbr>` and all other entities mentioned... This was the only one that worked! Thank you benesch!

Comment: Saved my life on FF45.

Comment: Worked on Firefox 86.