# Firefox CSS: Break word on dash

Tags: firefox, css, word-wrap

I have a HTML element that contains the text Snow-boarding, the container element doesn't have enough space to fit the text in one line so I need it to break in two.

In Chrome this is done automatically (I guess it assumes it's two words and leaves "Snow-" in the first line and "boarding" in the second).
In Firefox however it just leaves it in one line and it extends beyond the container. I was thinking on using the CSS property "word-wrap", which does break the word, but it doesn't break it in the dash (it leaves "Snow-boardi" in one line and "ng" in the other).

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jSrLb/5/

Any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/hyphens might help

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/904/8930?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753579/how-to-enable-line-break-at-hyphens-on-firefox